# Flask and Ajax current_user.id returns error

Tags: python, ajax, flask, flask-login

Trying to make ajax POST request on Flask, everything works fine except for when anything related to *current_user* is involved in the ajax request.

For example:

**python**

```
@app.route("/example", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mynumber = request.form['number']
        whatdoesntwork = mynumber + current_user.id
        return whatdoesntwork
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        var myNumber = 100;

        var toPost = {
            number : myNumber
        };

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/example',
            data : toPost,
            success : function (returnValue) {
                console.log(returnValue);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log("why doesnt it work?")
            }

        });

    });
});
```

*current_user.whatever* does fine everywhere else in the code
for exampe:

```
@app.route("/example", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example():
    flash(current_user.id, 'success)
    return render_template('eg.html')
```

the above code will display the user id as a flash message in the webpage

However, whenever *current_user.whatever* is involved in the ajax request, it raises an error with error 500 displaying on the console.

First time posting on stackoverflow, sorry if the question isn't straightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time when you asking questions here, please provide your error output. But, I guess I know what's happening.

`Flask-Login` user ids have the type `ObjectId`. They look like this:

```
{{
    $oid : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}}
```

You can serialize them by simply calling `str(current_user.id)`.

In your case:

```
@app.route("/example", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example():
if request.method == 'POST':
    mynumber = request.form['number']
    whatdoesntwork = mynumber + str(current_user.id)
    return whatdoesntwork
```